# The EL&U blog would like a piece on ELL

Tags: discussion, blog

Hello kind citzens of ELL. I am one of the curators of the [EL&U blog](http://english.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1).

We think it would be good to have someone from here contribute an article to the blog, introducing the ELL Stack Exchange and letting the EL&U faithful know what it's all about.

Does anyone here feel up to writing a few words?

There is an [EL&U blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog), for people who want to come and discuss ideas with me.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose this is in the first instance for the mods, who would speak as it were *ex cathedra*, to accept or decline. But if none of them feels up to it, I urge them to co-opt [**J.R.**](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18220/j-r), whose earlier [**opus**](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3723/24489) in this direction was about as graceful and succinct as it gets.

Comment: Stoney, thanks for your kind words. @Matt, I'll be happy to draft something up, and you can decide whether or not it's worth immortalizing in the ELU blog – unless you'd prefer the blog entry come from someone with less time at ELU?

Comment: I'm happy for it to come from you, @J.R. Anyone who we agree can properly represent ELL is fine by me.

Comment: I think @J.R. would be an excellent choice! And I think a blog entry would be a great way to further expose ELL to the ELU community :)

Comment: @J.R. So that you can post on the blog you need to visit the [blog back end](http://english.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin/) and then let me know that you have, so that waiwai can give you permission to create a post. It's a bit convoluted, but generally works out.

Comment: @Matt: I haven't forgotten about this but I'll need to find some time to carve out. I'll write something fairly soon.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not really up to that myself; I'm not particularly active here, and I'm still relatively new to ELL. However, whoever does take this on should consider a few things.

- We are NOT in competition with ELU. How forcefully this point should be made, and in what form, is up for debate. Regardless, it should be clear.
- We would strongly welcome more participation from the ELU community. There is currently some overlap, but it would be wonderful to have more of the regulars there stop by and offer their insights.
- We may want to talk briefly about how we treat new members here, and the line between a good question that is poorly written (due to unfamiliarity with English) and a question that is simply poor. (This isn't intended as a slur against any other SE site. I mean that we should present our site's development and policies clearly, without regard for the standards on other sites.)
- This is very definitely a Stack Exchange site. While its subject may be. . . non-traditional compared to the rest of the network, we are nonetheless finding our own identity within the SE framework. Some discussion of how we're getting there and how far we've come would be appropriate.

That all being said, I'm very happy that ELU has asked for this. I'd really like to see more interconnection between the sites, and a blog post dedicated to that should be good for both sites.